# How effective is Expect-CT against content inspection in an enterprise context?

Tags: tls, certificates, web, tls-intercept, certificate-transparency

[HPKP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning) was used to ensure that a browser accepts to connect to a site only if the public key he has on file is the one presented by the target site. I saw it as a way to make [deep content inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_content_inspection) more complicated (some sites would simply not accept the connection so there is nothing to inspect).

It seems however (from the Wikipedia page) that

> Most browsers disable pinning for certificate chains with private root
>   certificates to enable various corporate content inspection
>   scanners[6] and web debugging tools (such as mitmproxy or Fiddler).
>   The RFC 7469 standard recommends disabling pinning violation reports
>   for "user-defined" root certificates, where it is "acceptable" for the
>   browser to disable pin validation.[7]

So no protection anymore against deep inspection (I am not sure what the mechanism is for in that case but anyway).

This probably does not matter anymore taken that

> The mechanism was deprecated by the Google Chrome team in late 2017
>   because of its complexity and dangerous side-effects. Google
>   recommends using the Expect-CT as a safer alternative

[Certificate Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Transparency) is a public log of issued certificates

[image]

#### My questions:

- How does this log help to ensure that the certificate I see is the one actually presented by the target site, and not an intermediate one (where my session is terminated on the deep inspection engine, which replays the connection)
- If it indeed helps to do that, how does the "enterprise" restriction highlighted for HPKP above comes into play (if at all)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aim of certificate pinning is to protect against **malicious** man in the middle **attacks** and not against **legal** content inspection as done in companies and also desktop antivirus for **protection**, where the certificates are issued by an **explicitly trusted** local CA. it does not matter here that legal protection methods might also be used to invade the privacy - you need to discuss such things with your employer instead.

Insofar it makes sense to handle `Expect-CT` the same way and it is also documented to behave that way. From [MDN: Expect-CT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect-CT#Notes):

> Root CAs manually added to the trust store override and suppress Expect-CT reports/enforcement.

Comment: It seems a bit disturbing that Expect-CT is **suppressed** by the presence of a 3rd-party root -- this prevents the browser from tattling poorly-executed attempts by an _actual_ internal network attacker to a reporting server specified by the TLS terminator, as well as totally denying the report capability from any site _genuinely_ using a "3rd-party" root such as [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/) or [the United States Government](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=478418)...